# Equivalent of hashing SHA512 in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash, sha

I am trying to find out the equivalent function/method to get the same result in both PHP and MySQL after hashing.

**PHP**

```
$passphrase = "Information Technology";
echo hash('sha512',$passphrase);
```

> **Result:** 
> 9cb5bdceae139111d733736127eb380516d9cfce50882de7883321980962e6464711935316801f5689c3119c5ea3f5b79077b99e17cd355c6d5a8ff190ccb49d

**MySQL**

```
SET @passphrase = 'Information Technology';
SELECT SHA2(@passphrase,512);
```

> **Result:**  
> 3963623562646365616531333931313164373333373336313237656233383035313664396366636535303838326465373838333332313938303936326536343634373131393335333136383031663536383963333131396335656133663562373930373762393965313763643335356336643561386666313930636362343964

Is it possible to have a function that works and give results the same as for both?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @miken32 Server version: 5.6.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Can't reproduce on MySQL 5.5.53, MariaDB 10.0.30, or MariaDB 10.1.21

Comment: @miken32 Everything is fine now. Just restarted the server and it works suddenly. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Keep in mind SHA of any kind is not in any way appropriate for hashing passwords. These sorts of hashes are designed to be fast, and what you want for a password hash is something deliberately slow and difficult like Bcrypt or Scrypt. Whenever possible use a proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) method. MySQL does not have support for these, so you need to do validation application-side only.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the info! But the reason I asked this question is that I will use it only as a `SALT` to the key that I will be using for AES_DECRYPT.